# Extracting the current data value and corresponding subvalue from SQL tables

Tags: mysql, sql-server

If this has been answered, just link me to the answer and I'll sit there going 'Why didn't I think of that for the search?'

I have two databases which I'm trying to extract data from using SQL. The data bases are a parent and child.

Per - Parent, Hed - Child

Per has the following columns of information: Site, varfrom, varto, sdate, table and others which aren't important

Hed has the following columns of information: Site, varfrom, varto, table, release, name, and others which aren't important

Per example - the true and false are one of the extra columns

```
STATION VARFROM VARTO   SDATE   STIME   REFSTN  REFTAB
221209A 100.00  141 8/11/2006   1200.00 221209A 23  FALSE
221209A 100.00  141 22/04/2007  400.00  221209A 23  TRUE
221209A 100.00  141 30/04/2007  1600.00 221209A 24  FALSE
221209A 100.00  141 2/11/2007   0.00    221209A 24  TRUE
221209A 100.00  141 5/11/2007   2000.00 221209A 25  FALSE
221209A 100.00  141 24/11/2008  0.00    221209A 26  FALSE
221209A 100.00  141 16/02/2010  45.00   221209A 27  FALSE
221210A 100.00  141 22/08/1972  1545.00 221210A 1   FALSE
221210A 100.00  141 3/06/1978   1500.00 221210A 2   FALSE
221210A 100.00  141 5/07/1982   1130.00 221210A 1   FALSE
221210A 100.00  141 28/07/1984  1225.00 221210A 3   FALSE
221210A 100.00  141 24/02/1987  1200.00 221210A 2   FALSE
221210A 100.00  141 28/04/1988  1600.00 221210A 4   FALSE
221210A 100.00  141 5/01/1992   1430.00 221210A 3   FALSE
```

Hed example

```
STATION     VARFROM VARTO   TABLE   RELEASE NAME
221209A     100.00  141     23      0       23.0
221209A     100.00  141     24      0       24.0
221209A     100.00  141     25      2       25.02
221209A     100.00  141     25      1       25.01
221209A     100.00  141     25      0       25.00
221209A     100.00  141     26      0       26.00
221209A     100.00  141     27      0       27.00
221210A     100.00  141     1       3        1.03
221210A     100.00  141     1       2        1 B
221210A     100.00  141     2       6        2.06
221210A     100.00  141     2       5        2.05
221210A     100.00  141     2       4        2 D
221210A     100.00  141     3       1        3.01
221210A     100.00  141     3       0        3
221210A     100.00  141     4       2        4.02
221210A     100.00  141     4       1        4 A
```

So what I want is for it to return the most recent sdate for each site, then give me the current name for each site

So the answer for the example would be

```
Site    Varfrom Varto sdate      name
221209A 100.00  141   16/02/2010 27.00
221210A 100.00  141   5/01/1992   3.01
```

It doesn't matter if site comes from Per or Hed.

Currently I have any number of coding attempts which give me out everything, except that the name is incorrect. Below is one example. I just can't see how to make it give me the latest sdate with the right name.

```
select
 hed.site,
 hed.name,
 max(per.sdate) as "Period",
 hed.varfrom,
 hed.varto
from hed inner join per 
on hed.site=per.site AND
 hed.table=per.reftab
where
 hed.varfrom=100.00 
 AND  hed.varto=141
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Why have you tagged it as mysql AND sql-server? What database are you really using??

Comment: Do you mean you have 2 tables in 1 database, or do you actually have 2 separate databases with each 1 table? (according to the tags one in mysql and one in sql-server?)

Comment: Opps, that was me being enthusiastic with tags. Sorry. It's not sql-server. 

Per and Hed are separate but very linked. Each record in Per has one or more records in Hed. There's a third level down, which has multiple records for each Hed entry but I don't need those entries.

Think about it as Per is the overall information, Hed adds a bit more description to the data while the third level is the data. Per provides the times, to use the information in Hed and below.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
;with cte as (
select site,Varfrom ,Varto,reftable,sdate,r=ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by site order by sdate desc) from per
)

select per.site,per.Varfrom ,per.Varto,hed.name from cte per
inner join hed on per.site = hed.site and per.reftable=hed.reftable and per.r=1
```

Comment: Doesn't work sorry which is my fault for not tagging properly.